# A question about discrete Young's convolution inequality.

Tags: analysis, inequality

For sequence $\{ \delta_k \}_{k \geq 1} \in \mathcal{l}^2,$ that is, $\sum_{k \geq 1} \delta_k^2 < \infty,$ I want to prove the sequence $\{ \sum_{k= j-1}^{j+1}\ 2^{s(j-k)} \delta_k\}_{j \geq 1}$ also belongs to $\mathcal{l}^2.$(Assume $\delta_0=0$), and $s \in \mathbb{R}$ is a constant.

First I can prove it by Cauchy inequality:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{j \geq 1} (\sum_{k=j-1}^{j+1}\ 2^{s(j-k)} \delta_k)^2 \leq \sum_{j \geq 1}( \sum_{k=j-1}^{j+1} 2^{2s(j-k)} \sum_{k=j-1}^{j+1} \delta_k^2) =C_s \sum_{j \geq 1}\sum_{k=j-1}^{j+1} \delta_k^2=2\sum_{j \geq 1} \delta_k^2 < \infty.
\end{equation}

However, I want to prove this via Young's inequality. As we all know, the discrete Young's inequality is:
\begin{equation}
\| f * g\|_{\mathcal{l}^2} \leq \| f\|_{\mathcal{l}^1}\| g\|_{\mathcal{l}^2}.
\end{equation}
Is it possible to treat the sequence  $\{ \sum_{k= j-1}^{j+1}\ 2^{s(j-k)} \delta_k\}_{j \geq 1}$ as the sequence of $\{2^{s \cdot} * \delta_{\cdot} \}_{j \geq 1}$ ? But $2^{s \cdot} * \delta_{\cdot}$ actually is $\{\sum_{k \geq 1} 2^{s(j-k)}\delta_k\}_{j \geq 1},$ and $\sum_{k \geq 1}2^{s(j-k)}$ may not converge when $s<0$, so how can I modify the sequence to make Young's equality doable?